# How to get unique value in a DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datatable

I have the following code:

```
string strQuery = "";

using (SqlConnection scCon = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    using (SqlCommand scCmd = new SqlCommand("locZ", scCon))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        scCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        scCmd.Parameters.Add("@Loc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Loc.SelectedItem.Value;

        sda.SelectCommand = scCmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            strQuery += dr["Spec"].ToString() + "<br />";
        }

        Label1.Text = strQuery;

        Session.Add("DTTa", dt);
    }
}
```

How can I modify the code so I get only unique value for that column?

Comment: this [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/GinoAbraham/archive/2011/03/29/getting-distinct-column-values-from-a-cdatatable-again.aspx) might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LINQ` to `DataTable`:

```
var distinctRows = dt.AsEnumerable()
                     .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Spec"))
                     .Select(g => g.First());

foreach (DataRow dr in distinctRows) 
{
}
```

You can make it shorter and efficient using [`DistinctBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) method:

```
var distinctRows = dt.AsEnumerable()
                     .DistinctBy(row => row.Field<string>("Spec"));
```

If you wanna get only the value of one column and concatenate them you don't even need the `foreach`:

```
var distinctValues = dt.AsEnumerable()
                       .Select(row => row.Field<string>("Spec"))
                       .Distinct();
Label1.Text = string.Join("<br />", distinctValues);
```

Comment: I can't have `.AsEnumerable`. Is there an extension for this? Thanks.

Comment: `Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' to 'System.Data.DataTable'`

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge sorry it's my fault. you need to remove `.Rows`.

Comment: You sir is a genius! I wouldn't ever have figured it out. +1 and ACCEPTED. Thanks so much!